# Can brunch trigger actions upon changes in the watched folder?

Tags: watch, brunch

I discovered `brunch` and it may be a good alternative to `webpack` for my amateur, personal development needs.

I would be interested to trigger an action when the content of the `app` directory changes, in addition to the normal processing - something along the lines of

```
brunch watch --server --trigger='jekyll build'
```

which would also run `jekyll build` in addition to the processing of JS, `.vue` files, etc.

Today I run `jekyll build` in parallel to `webpack --dev-server`, which is suboptimal. I also understand that I could have a processing pipe driven by `gulp`, `grunt` or others but I would like to use (and possibly misuse) one tool to manage this extra task.